# php pass parameters to sql statement derived from the database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm newbie to Php and i'm trying to pass parameters to a SQL statement obtained from a table i maintain. The parameters passed could be product_id, dates  or in this case setting Limits. Here is what i've got so far...need advise to fix this..

DB statement stored in a table web_query:

```
SELECT * FROM adhoc_signal.`table 2` limit :startnum , :endnum
```

PHP script :

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (!$con) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Initialize variables
    $per_page=8;
    if (isset($_GET[“page”])) {
       $page = $_GET[“page”];
     }
    else {
     $page=1;
   } 

// Page will start from 0 and Multiple by Per Page
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

  $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT qry_text from web_query where report_id = 1") or die("Error : Failed to fetch Query records: " . mysql_error());  

           if (!$query) {  
                $error = 'Error fetching reports: ' . mysqli_error($con);  
                exit();  
           }
                // echo 'I got some webqry records';

              while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

              if (!empty($rows) || (array() !== $rows)) {
                // Following Problematic prepare statement...                                   
                 if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $rows['qry_text'])) {
                   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sssd', $start_page, $per_page);
                   $pagres = mysqli_query($con, $stmt);
                   $pagnum = mysqli_num_rows($pagres);
                   $pagnumcol= $pagres->field_count;

                 print "Value of stmt : $stmt magnum : $pagnum";
                 }
                 else {
                 print "Prepare statement is returning : False";
                 }
}
```

Alternatively if i change the DB SQL statement to : select * from adhoc_signal.`table 2` and modify the Php script without preparing it, they seem to work fine.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (!$con) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Initialize variables
    $per_page=8;
    if (isset($_GET[“page”])) {
       $page = $_GET[“page”];
     }
    else {
     $page=1;
   } 

// Page will start from 0 and Multiple by Per Page
$start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

  $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT qry_text from web_query where report_id = 1") or die("Error : Failed to fetch Query records: " . mysql_error());  

           if (!$query) {  
                $error = 'Error fetching reports: ' . mysqli_error($con);  
                exit();  
           }
                // echo 'I got some webqry records';

              while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {                 
              if (!empty($rows) || (array() !== $rows)) {
             $result = mysqli_query($con, $rows['qry_text']) or die("Error : Why is the Query failing : ". mysql_error());
             $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
             $numcol= $result->field_count;

             if ($num > 0) {
             print '<div class="panel panel-primary"> ';
             print '<div class="panel-heading"> ';
             print '<h3 class="panel-title">Results</h3> ';
             print '</div>';          
             print '<div id="gentable" class="table-responsive"> ';
             print '<table class="table-responsive table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" > ';
             print '<th><td><strong>Preferred Term</strong></td></th>';    

             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
               print " <tr> \n";
               foreach ($row as $field ){
                print " <td>$field</td> \n";
               } // end foreach
              print '</tr>';              
             } // end of while        
              print "</table>"; 
              print "</div>"; // End of panel body 
              print "</div>"; 
            }  // end of if
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have bound the parameter you need to execute that prepared statement and not do a `$pagres = mysqli_query($con, $stmt);`

Also you cannot mix proceedural and OO calling methods.

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $rows['qry_text'])) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sssd', $start_page, $per_page);

     //mysqli_query($con, $stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $pagnum = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    $pagnumcol= mysqli_stmt_field_count($stmt);
}
```

Also I dont think you want to be printing $stmt in this line

```
print "Value of stmt : $stmt magnum : $pagnum";
```

Comment: Thanks Riggsfolly i've implemented it and figured this was just one part of the solution. Post stmt execution i need to print the values returned by the SQL stmt. I've put in place... the following

Comment: I was referring to,  could you recommend me on the next steps i.e. the optimal way to print the values returned on execution of the sql stmt, specially when the contents of stmt are unknown.

Comment: This code does not seem to work, the following line is returning "false",     if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $rows['qry_text'])) {

Comment: That is more that likely the fault of what is on your database and returned in `$rows['qry_text']` echo the `$rows['qry_text']` and see if it makes sence, or try it using phpMyAdmin

Comment: You are right RiggsFolly, i updated the underlying sql_stmt from workbench to be "select * from xxx limit ?.?" and the statement executed successfully.  However the number of rows value is 0, when intact the table contains a few hundred rows. something i figure is fishy mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss', $start_from, $per_page);

Comment: It should be `LIMIT ?,?` a comma and not a dot between the from and to numbers.

Comment: It is a comma, and verified the values being passed " Value of Query returned : "SELECT * FROM adhoc_signal.`table 2` limit ?,?"...start_from: 0 ,per_page: 8 " where 0 and 8 are passed to mysql_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss', $start_from, $per_page);

Comment: Phew!! i got this to work using mysqli_query, instead of mysqli_prepare. What i see, if mysqli_prepare is used then i need to use mysqli_stmt_get_result....which for some reason...niether throws an error nor returns the results.....just curious how to overcome this..do i need to  use PDO..    $rows['qry_text'] = $rows['qry_text'] . "  LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);  if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) { $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt) or die("Error : Failed to Get result: " . mysqli_error($con)); // Problematic